# Distinct People Counting using OpenCV Python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision

I have a code that detects Cars in video and counts them, but there's an issue. If the same Car comes in the next frames, they get counted again. I tried from different resources but did not found any valid answer.

**My Code**

```
import cv2
backsub = cv2.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG()
capture = cv2.VideoCapture("C:/Users/chr04/Desktop/People and car counting/Car Counting/car video/video2.mp4")
best_id=0
i = 0
car = 0
if capture:
  while True:

    ret, frame = capture.read()
    if ret:
        fgmask = backsub.apply(frame, None, 0.01)
        contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(fgmask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                                           cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
        try: hierarchy = hierarchy[0]
        except: hierarchy = []
        for contour, hier in zip(contours, hierarchy):
            (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
            if w > 20 and h > 20:
                best_id+=1
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
                cv2.putText(frame, str(best_id), (x,y-5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                        0.5, (255, 0, 0), 2)
        print(best_id)        
        cv2.imshow("Track", frame)
        cv2.imshow("background sub", fgmask)
    key = cv2.waitKey(10)
    if key == ord('q'):
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the counter variable in the loop again and again(as you get the images frame by frame). That seems to be the issue here.

What I understand from your code is that the `best_id` is your counter variable. So just initialize this variable inside the loop (`best_id=0` inside while loop after `if ret` statement) and your code shall work fine as for every frame that you receive from the feed you need to reset this counter so that it can again start counting from `0` as done below.

```
if ret:
    #initializing best_id variable
    best_id = 0
    fgmask = backsub.apply(frame, None, 0.01)
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(fgmask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                                           cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

Comment: can you add some code hints inside answer for better understanding?

Comment: Let me try. Thanks

Comment: Same issue. actually i don't want to detect and count same car in next frame.

Comment: Sorry, I seem to have made an error myself. I have edited my answer. Initialize the best_id variable inside the `if ret:` statement inside the `while` loop, This should definitely work.

Comment: Still its detecting same car in next frame. I just want "if same car comes in next frame so it will not detected"

Comment: Well, I am a bit confused now, so you mean that if there is a red mercedes in the image and it gets detected once, your code shall not draw a bounding box over it again and it shouldn't count it's presence in the video?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228095/discussion-between-muhammad-rizwan-munawar-and-saurav-saha).